# Exchanging Azure AD Token for Keycloak token

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We have keycloak server integration. We are using only the APIs of Keycloak and no visual UI.

I have a nuxt.js app where we show External login options like Microsoft, Google, etc. On click, user is redirected to appropriate login flow where ex: Microsoft will handle the login part.

On redirect back to our endpoint. We get the code from Microsoft Azure AD login.

I am sending the code to Azure AD endpoint to get the access token: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

From the token I have the info (username and email). Assuming that the user does exist in the keycloak server, I want to login this user by exchanging the Azure AD token. I am not able to find the appropriate method or the endpoint to do this.

EDIT:

I found the following endpoint:
http://0.0.0.0:5001/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token

Form URL Encoded values:

```
client_id:mynuxtapp
client_secret:clientsecrethere
subject_token:mytokenhere
subject_token_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange
```

I am getting the error:

{
"error": "invalid_token",
"error_description": "Invalid token"
}

even though I am putting in the correct secret and AD token